# Using "with" in the meaning of "contain"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which of the following constructions are equivalent to "contain"? Which ones are more idiomatic?

> - A web page **showing** the search results for a product
> - A web page **of** the search results for a product
> - A web page **with** the search results for a product
> - A web page **containing** the search results for a product
> - An HTML element **containing** the text "StackExchange"
> - An HTML element **with** the text "StackExchange"
> - An HTML element **labeled with** the text "StackExchange"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sentence about the web page:

Both *showing* and *with* sound perfectly fine to me, the first one probably being the most idiomatic. I am not sure whether *of* would be correct in this case, but I cannot recall having seen that preposition being used before in this context. Now, the word *containing* also sounds odd. Let's have a look at its definition first:

> to have something inside or include something as a part ([source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contain))

Search results are shown **on** a page, not **in** a page and rather than being "a part" of the page, the search results are really what the page is all about so *contain* does not really seem the right verb to use.

I think *showing* is your best option here.

---

For the sentence about the HTML-tag:

Again, *with* seems to be fine here and as opposed to the other sentence, I think *containing* can perfectly be used as well. In HTML, as you probably know, the text for an element are **placed within** its tags, meaning that the text is **inside** the HTML element, so the definition of *contain* fits perfectly. Allow me to illustrate with an example:

```
<span>StackExchange</span>
```

The text is *contained* within the `<span>` tags here.

Now, about *labeled with*: I wouldn't use this phrase here. It could cause confusion since it could be interpreted as not actually having the text within the HTML element, but rather having it in the `title` attribute or the `data-label` or similar attributes:

```
<span title="StackExchange">Not SE</span>
```

or

```
<span data-label="StackExchange">Not SE</span>
```

---

### In short

To describe the search results on a web page, *showing* is probably the way to go. To describe the text within an HTML element, you can definitely use *containing*. In both cases, *with* seems to be working fine as well.